# Proof Of König's Lemma

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

I am trying, carefully, to prove König's Lemma that an infinite binary tree $T$ has an infinite simple path.

Let $R$ denote the root vertex of $T$. If I start at $v_1=R$, there must be a vertex adjacent to $R$, call it $v_2$, such that infinitely many vertices of $T$ are reachable by going up the tree from $v_2$.

If not, the tree would be a finite tree (finite union of finite sets of vertices).

I can repeat this process. Whenever I am at vertex $v_n$, I can find a vertex $v_{n+1}$ such that there are infinitely many vertices still available above $v_{n+1}$ in the tree.

By induction, for any $n$ I can have that there exists a path of length $n$, in $T$.

How do I get from this an infinite path? Surely mathematical induction gives me the existence of an arbitrarily long finite path, which is not the same thing?

> **Edit:** Ah, I think I've got it. I can order the vertices in each level of the tree from the left to the right, and at every step define $p(n)=$ the leftmost (resp. rightmost) vertex that has infinitely many vertices above it. Induction gives me the path $p(1)p(2)\ldots p(n)$ for every natural $n$ and then the infinite path is the set-theoretic union over $\Bbb N$ of these arbitrarily long finite paths?

Comment: Your edit does the trick. Good job!

Comment: And I don't have to choose these orderings (of each level) one by one (which would require the axiom of countable choice or somesuch) because I can choose one enumeration of the entire tree, and the orderings of each level can be inherited from that. Therefore, each enumeration of the tree defines a unique, infinite, path.

Comment: Yes, that works. In my answer, the 'left successor' of each vertex is labeled $0$ and the 'right successor' is labeled $1$.

Comment: The more I think about stuff like this and the less I believe the axiom of countable choice. I *felt* stuck when I hadn't thought of my edit. The axiom of countable choice seems to say I wasn't stuck! But I swear I was!

Comment: Countable choice would have allowed you to be a bit more careless - but (as both our approaches show) - it wasn't necessary to overcome this bump.

Comment: @Stefan But you are assuming that your tree is a subtree of $2^{<\omega} $. If all you know is that each node has two successors, you need countable choice or some such to organize the construction.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo The tree is binary and thus countable (a countable union of finite sets). Fixing such an enumeration lets me label the nodes in the way I did.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo I debated whether or not I should be more explicit about that and if I should mention that this may no longer work once we allowed for infinitely many successors, but since this didn't seem to be the part OP struggled with, I decided not to. However, you get the right idea that to me, a binary tree is a subset of $^{<\omega} 2$. In this case, however, that doesn't matter. Even in the absence of choice.

Comment: Yeah I reckon as soon as there exists a bijection between V(G) and N, you can use this numbering to define a path, by choosing the vertex having the smallest number at each step. Once you have chosen a bijection between V(G) and N, the path in the proof is determined.

Comment: Countable unions of finite sets are not necessarily countable in the absence of choice, @Stefan.

Comment: Really? So how would the whole Konig's Lemma, Weak Konig's Lemma work in reverse mathematics... if you require choice...

Comment: @JohnSmith In reverse mathematics, the trees you consider are explicitly countable, say, subtrees of $\omega^{<\omega} $, for instance. The point in reverse mathematics is that computing branches is hard (meaning, branches tend to be non-computable, even in computable trees). To get an idea of why this is so, think of the given argument: At each stage you are asking if a set is infinite. Computable sets are $\Delta^0_1$, but asking if a set is infinite is a $\Pi^0_2$ question ($\forall n\,\exists m>n\dots $). (Of course, some trees have recursive branches.)

Comment: Hmm so sometimes a countable union of finite sets can be proved countable without CC, but sometimes not? I feel like this leads to a whole new question.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Oh, right. The "proof" that I had in mind requires that there is  a total order on the union and that might not be the case - without a weak form of choice. Thank you for spotting my mistake.

Comment: I think I understand now! For Konig's Lemma to be a theorem and not somehow an aspect of AC, the vertex set should be assumed countable, since a countable union of pairs might not be countable if the pairs are members of a set that is not well-ordered.

Comment: It's counterintuitive to think that saying "every vertex has upward degree two" is so different from saying "every vertex has two neighbours above it, indexed by {L,R} (or {0,1})". But in the former case, you have no idea what the order of your graph is, due to a lack of a choice function that allows you to prove your vertex set is countable.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it, @John. Sorry that I spread some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rearrange your argument a little bit. We recursively construct a set $\{ s_n \mid n \in \mathbb N \}$ of $0/1$ sequences such that $s_0 = ()$ is the root of your tree. Given $s_n$, we let $s_{n+1} = s_{n} \ ^\frown (0)$, if there are infinitely many points above $s_{n} \ ^\frown (0)$ and otherwise we let $s_{n+1} = s_{n} \ ^\frown (1)$. Note that in either case there are infinitely many points above $s_{n+1}$ - so this construction never breaks down.

Let $s$ be the unique infinite $0/1$ sequence such that the first $n-1$ entries of $s$ agree with $s_{n}$ - for every $n \in \mathbb N$. By construction $s$ is an infinite branch through our tree.

Answer (score 1):

I shall summarise some of the further points discussed in the Comments in this Answer.
Proofs of Konig's Infinity Lemma (for Graphs and for Trees) (e.g. the [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_lemma)) build the path vertex by vertex with two aspects which require discussion:

1. The *determination* of which successor node(s) actually have an infinite path though them;
2. The *selection process* whenever two (or more in general Trees) meet condition 1

For condition 1. In **ZF** Set theory the arguments of the proof are sufficient to establish that at least one such successor node exists without having to determine which one that is, for the purpose of the proof.

For condition 2. The selection process is a *calculation* if the Vertex set is well ordered: one simply uses $min\{V0,V1\}$ in the ordering when $\{V0,V1\}$ are the two successors meeting condition 1. However if the Vertex set is not well ordered the above calculation is not defined and so the Axiom of Dependent choice (or similar form of Weak Axiom of Choice) is required for the proof to go through.

In other words in **ZFC** Set Theory (which is the usual framework for Graph Theory and other parts of mathematics) Konig's Lemma holds unconditionally. In **ZF** Set theory Konig's Lemma is only valid with the additional condition that the Vertex Set is well ordered. This condition *is* met in the important special case in which the Vertex Set is (provably) countable. So for *countable* binary trees Konig's Lemma again holds unconditionally in **ZF** Set Theory.

This leaves open the question of actually *calculating* which successor node(s) meet condition 1. Although not required in the **ZF** proof, one can see that this would require an "infinite lookahead" to check that a given candidate Vertex actually led to an infinite path. This process is clearly not recursive and in [Reverse Mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) it was established that (for a binary tree) it is equivalent to a non-constructive axiom called Weak Konig's Lemma ($WKL_0$). For an *arbitrary* finitely branching tree it is equivalent to a stronger axiom called $ACA_0$. All trees in Reverse Mathematics are countable and so the **ZF** proof of Konig's Lemma applies.